# css hover effect fixed to dev element and not extending when scrolling

Tags: css, hover

I have a parent dev with css as follows :
`overflow :auto;white-space: nowrap;` 
and few inner devs (with hovering css) which holds some text that may be too long and requires scrolling to the right,but the hover color is fixed to the dev width 
and not extending while scrolling to right.Here is the hover css :

```
    {
    border: 1px solid #87b4d1;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Open Sans Regular, arial !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    cursor: default;
    height: 17px !important;
    line-height:16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    border-right:1px\9;
    padding-right:1px\9;
    border-right:1px/0;
    padding-right:1px/0;
}
```

how can i make the hover css extended while scrolling and not fixed with the inner dev width ?
[image]
After scrolling

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) out of your code?

Comment: yes i will after a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the property on the inner divs

```
width:100%;padding-right:100%;
```

And it worked for me.